# How to change the defaults system java encode form in windows?

Tags: java, javac, encode

When I tried to compile (use javac)some java sources files include a comment line which has some unrecognized char like ascii code 129 (~A), error got.

The sources code looks like the following:

```
 // ascii 129 is ? (Acutally it show ~A in VIM but show ? when I directly copy it here)
```

The above code line is a comment, it should not cause any error, but if it did, I think it should be a problem about the jave encode form, how can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Wa

Comment: `129` is not a valid ASCII code. ASCII only goes up to `127`. Codepoint `129` is also reserved and undefined in `ISO-8859-1` which Unicode is a superset of. It is also undefined in `Windows-1252` which is popular on Windows on computers in the western world. In short, it does not represent a character in some of the most popular encodings, so i'm really curious which encoding was used to encode the Java source file in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this answer. It worked for me, and I don't have to worry about it anymore :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/623036/971592

Answer (score 0):

Pick the correct encoding of the java source. UTF-8 would be a good requirements standard. One can use the open source editor JEdit to test which encoding the source actually is in. The java tool **native2ascii** can convert.

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 ...
```

Comment: How to change the default system encode form so that I don`t have to add "-encoding xxx" after javec everytime?

Comment: Use a build system, like the easy **maven**, where you can configure the encoding once. An IDE, like NetBeans, would provide editing in some encoding, and compiling in some encoding too. The problem of editing in some non-default encoding does not seem worth changing the Windows encoding. You can associate in Windows .java with an editor/compiler with encoding command-line parameter.

Comment: I found a solution, in Windows, set a system variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS to be "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8", it will work.